# C++ type comparison: typeid vs double dispatch dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, typeid, double-dispatch

Are there any performance or robustness reasons to prefer one over the other?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct B
{
    virtual bool IsType(B const * b) const { return IsType2nd(b) && b->IsType2nd(this); }
    virtual bool IsType2nd(B const * b) const { return dynamic_cast<decltype(this)>(b) != nullptr; }
};

struct D0 : B
{
    virtual bool IsType(B const * b) const { return IsType2nd(b) && b->IsType2nd(this); }
    virtual bool IsType2nd(B const * b) const { return dynamic_cast<decltype(this)>(b) != nullptr; }
};

struct D1 : B
{
    virtual bool IsType(B const * b) const { return IsType2nd(b) && b->IsType2nd(this); }
    virtual bool IsType2nd(B const * b) const { return dynamic_cast<decltype(this)>(b) != nullptr; }
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    B b, bb;
    D0 d0, dd0;
    D1 d1, dd1;

    cout << "type B  == type B  : " << (b.IsType(&bb)   ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type D0 : " << (b.IsType(&dd0)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type D1 : " << (b.IsType(&dd1)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type B  : " << (d0.IsType(&bb)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type D0 : " << (d0.IsType(&dd0) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type D1 : " << (d0.IsType(&dd1) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type B  : " << (d1.IsType(&bb)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type D0 : " << (d1.IsType(&dd0) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type D1 : " << (d1.IsType(&dd1) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type B  : " << (typeid(b) == typeid(bb)   ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type D0 : " << (typeid(b) == typeid(dd0)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type D1 : " << (typeid(b) == typeid(dd1)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type B  : " << (typeid(d0) == typeid(&bb) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type D0 : " << (typeid(d0) == typeid(dd0) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type D1 : " << (typeid(d0) == typeid(dd1) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type B  : " << (typeid(d1) == typeid(bb)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type D0 : " << (typeid(d1) == typeid(dd0) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type D1 : " << (typeid(d1) == typeid(dd1) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
}
```

output:

```
type B  == type B  : true 
type B  == type D0 : false
type B  == type D1 : false
type D0 == type B  : false
type D0 == type D0 : true 
type D0 == type D1 : false
type D1 == type B  : false
type D1 == type D0 : false
type D1 == type D1 : true 

type B  == type B  : true 
type B  == type D0 : false
type B  == type D1 : false
type D0 == type B  : false
type D0 == type D0 : true 
type D0 == type D1 : false
type D1 == type B  : false
type D1 == type D0 : false
type D1 == type D1 : true
```

Comment: In my experience, any attempt to figure out the actual type of the polymorphic class indicates a design flaw.

Comment: @SergeyA, agreed. I inherited code that uses type switch everywhere, and I'm attempting to improve it.

Comment: do you accept also a third option or you are interested only in the twos above?

Comment: @skypjack, what's the 3rd option?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Sorry if I'm late, I've been busy. The 3rd option depends on your requirements. Is it a hierarchy of 1 level as in the example? Can you instantiate `B` in your real problem?

Comment: @skypjack, actually the hierarchy is many levels, and yes I can instantiate `B`.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Added as an answer, even if that's not properly an answer. Hoping you find it interesting (at least as a bad example not to be followed!!). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the design perspective, the double dispatch is far more flexible:

- Currently you check for strict egality between the type with `IsType2nd(b) && b->IsType2nd(this)`.  But may be at some time you'd like to derivate further
- But one day you may want to derivate further D1, but still want to consider it as if it where a D1 object when comparing types.  This kind of special case is easily done with double dispatch.

This flexibility comes at a cost: the assembler code would use 2 indirect calls via a vtable, plus a dynamic cast.

The direct type information is not the greatest design, as Sergey pointed out: It will always be a strict type comparison, with no special case possible.

This inflexibility comes with advantage of simplicity in code generation:  the code has just to get the dynamic type information at the start of the vtable (and the compiler can easily optimise this fetch away for object where the type is known at compile time.

For the sake of curiosity, here [some code generated](https://goo.gl/wQZNQQ) : he typeid is optimised away at compile time, whereas the double displatch still relies on indirect calls.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, it follows another possible solution that neither uses `typeid` nor relies on `dynamic_cast`.

I've added a couple of additional examples to show how you can easily define a *family* type (as an example, here both `D1` and `D1Bis` appear as being of the same family type, even if they are actually different types).
Not sure that's a desired feature, anyway...

Hoping it's of interest for you.

```
#include<iostream>

struct BB {
    virtual unsigned int GetType() = 0;

    bool IsType(BB *other) {
        return GetType() == other->GetType();
    }

protected:
    static unsigned int bbType;
};

unsigned int BB::bbType = 0;

struct B: public BB {
    unsigned int GetType() override {
        static unsigned int bType = BB::bbType++;
        return bType;
    }
};

struct D0: public B {
    unsigned int GetType() override {
        static unsigned int d0Type = BB::bbType++;
        return d0Type;
    }
};

struct D1: public B {
    unsigned int GetType() override {
        static unsigned int d1Type = BB::bbType++;
        return d1Type;
    }
};

struct D1Bis: public D1 { };

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    B b, bb;
    D0 d0, dd0;
    D1 d1, dd1;
    D1Bis d1Bis;

    cout << "type B  == type B  : " << (b.IsType(&bb)   ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type D0 : " << (b.IsType(&dd0)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type D1 : " << (b.IsType(&dd1)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type B  == type D1BIS : " << (b.IsType(&d1Bis)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type B  : " << (d0.IsType(&bb)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type D0 : " << (d0.IsType(&dd0) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type D1 : " << (d0.IsType(&dd1) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D0 == type D1BIS : " << (d0.IsType(&d1Bis) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type B  : " << (d1.IsType(&bb)  ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type D0 : " << (d1.IsType(&dd0) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type D1 : " << (d1.IsType(&dd1) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
    cout << "type D1 == type D1Bis : " << (d1.IsType(&d1Bis) ? "true " : "false") << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is basically the type enum solution that was common during the C language era.

Comment: Well, this is still used today, usually with the `CRTP` idiom, to give a type to the derived classes (as an example, `entityx` does something like that), but it doesn't fit well with hierarchies having more than one level, so... I tried to adapt the solution to your problem.

Comment: Not necessary for CRTP, because you can use template type deduction to discover the template parameter of the base class.

Comment: *Usually* does not mean *necessarily*. Anyway, I spoke about a third option that works, this one works, feel free not to use it. :-)